# Semanticamente, devo optar por ul ou article ao exibir produtos?

Tags: html5, semântica

Estou fazendo a marcação dos produtos listados na home, estou utilizando HTML5 para estruturar as páginas, minha intenção é definir um conteúdo semântico. Pois então me deparei com as seguintes possibilidades de marcação:

Envolver a vitrine de produtos com uma section e listar os produtos como uma lista.

```
<section>
    <h1>Semana da tecnologia</h1> <!-- Titulo da vitrine de produtos-->
    <ul>
        <li>
            <div></div> <!-- Aqui é o wrap do produto (titulo, foto, preco, etc...) -->
        </li>
        <li>
            <div></div> <!-- Aqui é o wrap do produto (titulo, foto, preco, etc...) -->
        </li>
    </ul>
</section>
```

Ou ao inves de lista usar article para cada produto

```
<section>
    <h1>Semana da tecnologia</h1> <!-- Titulo da vitrine de produtos-->
    <article></article><!-- Aqui é o wrap do produto (titulo, foto, preco, etc...) -->
    <article></article><!-- Aqui é o wrap do produto (titulo, foto, preco, etc...) -->
</section>
```

Acredito eu que ambas as formas oferecem um marcação semântica para o conteúdo, porém por qual deveria optar?

Comment: Indico o article. Veja o doc do schema.org http://schema.org/Product

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> "A tag `<article>` especifica um conteúdo independente,
>   auto-suficiente. Um article deve fazer sentido e poder ser distribuído
>   independente do restante do site."
>   [W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_article.asp)

Considerando que seu produto vai seguir um modelo específico e trabalhará de forma dinâmica, acho que faz mais sentido o uso do article.

Além de deixar visivelmente mais limpo, ficará mais simples de trabalhar um script de backend para gerar esses produtos com esta tag.

Answer (score 0):

HTML significa HyperText Markup Language. É uma linguagem de marcação. O objetivo original era uma estrutura que funcionasse por si só, e o CSS "complementaria".

Não é a realidade mais. Sem o CSS pouquíssimos sites funcionariam. Tendo isso em conta, muitas vezes é necessário usar tags HTML que simplifiquem o trabalho de " estilizar" um site, mas não é o objetivo do HTML, portanto, semanticamente, o ideal seria utilizar o `article`.

A tag `ul` representa "listas não-ordenadas" (unordered list), enquanto a tag article foi inserida no html5 especificamente para sanar a discussão `ul` versus `div`.

Vale considerar que é necessário sempre pesar a "pureza" do código contra a velocidade de implementação. O "correto" nem sempre entrega o projeto nem paga as contas, e esse dilema não tem solução definitiva, mas do ponto de vista de obedecer aos padrões, o `article` é o caminho. :D